# Is it OK to discourage new developers and helping members just because one has extended privileges?

Tags: discussion

Before I explain what I feel is going wrong: I'd like to say that it is not because my correct answer was downvoted. If that would have been the case I would have deleted the answer.

What I feel is going wrong:

Take [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34585944/implement-google-admob-in-android/) as an example:

1. The new user was dealt with in a harsh manner instead of trying to encourage them.
2. The answer was criticized as soon as it was posted, without giving time to put enough details. I (and I believe many others too...) start an answer with basic pointers and then figure out other additional details to help.

I hope this does not sound like cribbing :) I just felt like this is a problem and will discourage new users. I've seen this in other posts too.

Comment: Its generally expected that an answer is a complete solution to the problem if you post it. This is common practice here. For finding further details and clarifying the question, comments exist.

Comment: @Magisch no, in this case it was not about looking details. The answer was valid but with a brief explanation and a link to documentation. The steps were added later.

Comment: @Virus The first draft of your answer was almost completly link only. These types of answer are generally speaking discouraged on SO.

Comment: That question made me punch a baby.  Why do you hate babies?

Comment: "Without giving time to put enough details" you had a gun to your head to submit your answer? The one who criticized your answer saw your draft before you posted? No. You posted an incomplete answer. The curt and short reply here is : you took a bet you'd have time to edit it in shape. You lost the bet. Period. Don't post incomplete answers, it won't happen.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a difference between "discouraging" and "criticizing".

The answer posted was *very* minor, at first:

> You need to display an interstitial ad at a logical point in your app. e.g. exiting activity of after an action - [Interstitial Ad](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial?hl=en)

I'd have downvoted that too.

Sure, a user *can* improve an answer after posting it. But when you post a incomplete answer, you're just gambling that no-one cares enough to downvote it, untill you update it.

Generally, answers posted to SO should be *complete*.
A link to the documentation is *not* a "complete" answer.

Answer (score 6):

***Bad questions often lead to bad answers.***

To start off, the question itself is bad. Next, to add to it, you posted an answer that is as bad as the question.

Coming back to your question :

> Is it ok to discourage new developers and helping members just because
>   one has extended privileges?

No!. The question was NOT DVed because it was from a new user. It was DVed because it was really bad. Next, frankly speaking, your answer doesn't help anyone out there.

On SO we strive to help new users but we think quality is more important :)